# If the highest federal tax rate is 33% and the highest provincial tax rate is 25.75%. why is the marginal tax rate 53% rather than 58.75% (Quebec)?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, canada, quebec

If I understand correctly, the total tax is basically the sum of federal taxes and provincial taxes, so for Quebec this should give a marginal tax rate of 58.75% (33% federal and 25.75% provincial). So why do all the tax calculators give around 53%?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.taxtips.ca/qctax/federaltaxabatement.htm

> Under an agreement between the federal government and Quebec, most
> Quebec taxpayers get a federal tax abatement (reduction) of 16.5% of
> either basic federal tax (line 57 on Schedule 1) or minimum tax,
> whichever is greater.  The tables of marginal tax rates for Quebec
> include the reduction for the abatement.

So 33% * (1-16.5%) + 25.75% = 53.305%